# How do I find a match which has already been captured by another match?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace all occurrences of matches in a string if some parts have already been captured:

E.g. Given the pattern "AB|BC" and the target "ABC" we match "AB" but not "BC"

I've been trying to understand the various regex grouping options ([Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#noncapturing_group)) without success. I'm probably barking up the wrong tree. :-(

```cs
var test = Regex.Replace("(AB)(BC)(AC)(ABC)", @"AB|BC", string.Empty);
```

In the example, test evaluates to "()()(AC)(C)", but what I actually want is "()()(AC)()"

Comment: Have you tried "A|B|C" ?

Comment: But do you want to match or replace? Overlapping matches for these two operations need different approaches.

Comment: Thanks terry, but that would capture any instance of A, B or C (eg AA, AC etc)- not just AB and BC

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I want to replace, so that "(AB)(BC)(AC)(ABC)" evaluates to "()()(AC)()"

Comment: And to make it clear, are `AB` and `BC` static patterns known beforehand or are they user-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without taking care of the parenthesis, you cou use and alternation with an optional character using the question mark.

Match `AB` with an optional `C` or Match an optional `A` followed by `BC`. In the replacement use an empty string.

```
ABC?|A?BC
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J7aRl4/1)

Including the parenthesis you might use a capturing group or lookarounds to assert what is on the left and on the right are opening and closing parenthesis.

```
(?<=\()(?:ABC?|A?BC)(?=\))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\()` Assert what is on the left is `(`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `ABC?` Match AB with optional C
    -`|` Or
  - `A?BC` Match optional A and BC
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(?=\))` Assert what is on the right is `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J7aRl4/2)

Comment: The real problem is rather more complicated, but I believe that this would solve it. Ta v much :-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to *consume* the overlaps buddy, it has to be matched.
Therefore, one side of the alternation has to include its buddies last
or first literal (doesn't have to be both).

`AB|BC` ~ `ABC?|BC` = `A?BC|AB`